# Is there a PHP version of mockito?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

When I go to the official page of [mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-for-other-languages) page, they officially point PHP user to a git repository that is not updated since 7 years ago. I have tried installing that repository, but it seems it is not working for PHP 7.

May I ask if there are any other alternative now?

Comment: Generally the most popular mocking and testing framework for PHP is PHPUnit.

Comment: I am not sure, new to testing in PHP. Just heard from a friend that mockito is a must-have and is a cross-language library. Is that PHPUnit can provide all mocking function that mockito provides? Or is there other alternatives?